# How do I schedule a task to run when a new file is detected in a folder?

Tags: windows-7, task-scheduler, synctoy

I'd like to use windows task scheduler to execute a synctoy synchronization. Basically

`C:\Program Files\SyncToy 2.1\SyncToyCmd.exe -R "Contacts Sync"`

I'd like the task only to run when a new file is detected in a folder, instead of every 5 minutes.

One idea I've had is to configure audit logs so that an event is generated when the folder is accessed. But that seems indirect. Is there another way to trigger a windows task?